# Google chart SQL and Json

Tags: json, google-visualization

Looking to add SQL insert into my google charts. I looked at the google example in the API, however that uses a set file containing the values. I have seen a few examples on here but they seem rather complicated.

I want to populate the chart with data from my DB, im using depreciated code, its just an example. I have read about using `json_encode`. However when I apply it to my output I get quotations which according to the google example below are not needed.

In short how would I go about getting this simple query displaying in the chart below?

**Query example**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
   $data1[]=    "['" . $row1['Date'] . "','" . $row1['SpeciesB'] . "']";
   echo   "['" . $row['Date'] . "','" . $row['SpeciesA'] . "','" . $row['SpeciesB'] . "'],";
 echo "<br>";
 }
```

**Outputs**

```
 ['2013-08-06','1','1'],
 ['2013-08-13','1','2'],
 ['2013-08-20','2','2'],
 ['2013-08-27','3','1'],
 ['2013-09-17','4','1'],
```

or

`print_r($data1);`

```
  Array ( [0] => ['2013-08-06','1'] [1] => ['2013-08-13','2'] [2] => ['2013-08-20','2'] [3] => ['2013-08-27','1'] [4] => ['2013-09-17','1'] )
```

**Example of what google expects**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Species A', 'Species B'],
      ['20/05/2006',  1,      1],
      ['20/06/2006',  3,      2],
      ['20/07/2006',  2,      2],
      ['20/08/2006',  3,      1]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Site Dynamics'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use json_encode to take care of the details of building your output for you, as your current method will run into problems in Internet Explorer (you will always have a training comma after your last row of data, which will cause IE to bomb).  Try this instead:

```
$dataArray = array(array('Date', 'Species A', 'Species B'));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // parse the "SpeciesA" and "SpeciesB" values as integer (int) or floating point (float), as appropriate
    $dataArray[] = array($row['Date'], (int) $row['SpeciesA'], (int) $row['Speciesb']);
}
```

and in the javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>);
```

Comment: I did notice the trailing comma, I will give your method ago. But how would I use Json method? as when I use echo `json_encode` the format doesn't look right i.e. everything had "" around

Comment: JSON requires object property names and strings to be enclosed in double-quotes, so that might be what you are seeing.  Also, by default, MySQL outputs numbers as strings, so you have to parse them as ints or floats before adding them to your output or json_encode will encode them as strings.

Comment: user19786, I fixed a typo in the code above.  Try it with the fix.