# Adding legend to Google chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to add the column headings to the legend in this line graph, they should be the first row within the data table. The graph works fine if I remove the headings, however when I try load it with the headings I am getting nothing. Below is the output of the code that creates the input table it looks correct based on the google api example. Thanks

`['Date','Species A', 'Species B'],['2013-08-27',3,1], ['2013-09-17',4,1], ['2013-08-23',1,1], ['2013-08-10',2,8]`

**The relevant bits of code**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Species");
 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $data1[]=    "['" . $row1['Date'] . "'," . $row1['SpeciesA'] . "," . $row1['SpeciesB'] . "]";
 }

        $headings = "['Date','Species A', 'Species B'],";
        $headingdata = $headings . implode(",\n",$data1);
        echo $headingdata;
?> 

  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart()
   {
          // Create the data table.
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Species A');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Species B');
              data.addRows([

              <?php echo $headingdata;?>
              ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the DataTable like that, you don't want to include the `$headings` data in  the data you are passing to the DataTable's #addRows method.  Those should only be included if you are using the arrayToDataTable constructor.

Most of the charts will include the column labels as the series labels in the legend by default.

If you use the solution I posted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310727/google-chart-sql-and-json/18315834#18315834), you shouldn't have any problems with this.