# google chart api date format

Tags: date, google-visualization

The below answer suggested works using mysql_ however I have decided to switch to PDO for the increased security if offers. However When I apply the same code, I am struggling to get it to work.I had to switch the `while` to `foreach` for PDO.

**UPDATE: Using PHP PDO**

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM userrecords";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

 foreach ($data as $row)
 {
  $dateArray = explode('-', $row['eventdate']);
  $year = $dateArray[0];
  $month= $dateArray[1] - 1;
  $day= $dateArray[2];

  $dataArray[] = "[new Date ($year, $month, $day), {$row['scientificname']}, {$row['category_of_taxom']}]";

 }
 echo $dataArray;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the solution from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310727/google-chart-sql-and-json/18315834#18315834), you have to parse your dates into javascript's Date object format:

```
$dataArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $dateArray = explode('-', $row['Date']);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 since javascript months are zero-indexed
    $day = $dateArray[2];
    $dataArray[] = "[new Date($year, $month, $day), {$row['SpeciesA']}, {$row['Speciesb']}]";
}
```

Because the json_encode function will break the dates here, we have to parse it into the DataTable constructor a bit differently:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Species A');
data.addColumn('number', 'Species B');
data.addRows(<?php echo '[' . implode(',', $dataArray) . ']'; ?>);
```

Comment: The months in the table are one month out, whether I add, subtract or leave the $month variable alone. Whatever month it should be it is one month into the future?

Comment: The months shouldn't be off if you follow the code I posted above (assuming that your date strings are in the format `"yyyy-mm-dd"`).  Post the javascript as rendered by the server (open in a browser, view source, and copy the javascript), raw data from the database (before it gets processed in PHP), and a screenshot showing the months being off by 1.

Comment: Its ok, They are correct, I was looking at the implode text and seeing it said 1 month behind (because we -1) and thinking why is the chart +1 month that value. I got the logic stuck in my head wrongly, its had been a long day!